# Putting Markers inside Venue

Tags: java, android, here-api

I am currently working on the Venues3D provided by Here-api.
Here is my problem:

- **I want to put a Marker inside a Venue and ontop of a Space.**

Here is a example picture of what I want from the official Here WeGo Android-App.

[Example: Marker ontop of Space inside venue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oGOT.jpg)

I already checked out the "normal" MapMarkers but they only take GeoCoordinate and not Spaces inside a Venue.
The Venue3DTutorial didn't help too much either. There is a routing option shipped with it that pins the markers when calculating a route between two points inside a venue. But this is done in the background.(Also called Flags)

Is there an other Class that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Space has a center as GeoCoordinate, so you can use it for your marker. You should also specify correct parameters, so the marker will be visible on top of the venue. Here's an example how to do it with a marker similar to the one in HERE WeGo app:

```
public void showMarker(Space space) {
    Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.your_marker_image);
    Image image = new Image();
    image.setBitmap(bitmap);

    m_marker = new MapMarker(space.getCenter(), image);
    // Set anchor point to the centre-bottom area of the marker
    m_marker.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(image.getWidth() / 2f, image.getHeight()));
    m_marker.setOverlayType(MapOverlayType.FOREGROUND_OVERLAY);
    m_marker.setZIndex(100);

    // You can get map from VenueMapFragment, for example.
    getMap().addMapObject(m_marker);
}
```